# What is the best practice for handling dead or discontinued SKUs on an E-commerce site?

Tags: e-commerce

What is the best practice for handling dead or discontinued SKUs on an E-commerce site?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using an ecommerce CMS/framework? What language is the site written in? What DB software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a product status, at least one of which means the product can no longer be purchased or viewed.

If the product cannot be viewed make sure your site gracefully deals with old links to the product page.

I do not see the need to actually delete the sku.